# Windows Defender - Windows Server 2019 client onboarding - via squid proxy server

Tags: azure, proxy, squid, windows-defender

I have prepared Azure environment, VMs:winsrv2019, winsrv2012. Both VMs are deployed in the isolated azure subnet (only traffic to security tools and to proxy server is allowed). In second subnet I deployed Ubuntu 16 proxy squid server, I configured squid, used user and password for authentication, traffic to Windows Defender Security Center web platform is allowed. I have Windows Defender Security Center web platform configured. I was able to on-board winsrv2012 VM (MMA agent configuration using proxy server and user and password, I used provided by MS workspace ID and Workspace key), and this VM is successfully on-boarded to Windows Defender Security Center web platform. In case of winsrv2019 I have a problem. Connection winsrv2019 --> Proxy server has been tested using PowerShell, and its ok. On a VM I can use web browser and connect to public web sites via proxy server (once I select a public web site I am prompted for user and pass authentication). `Sense` service (Defender service for windows server 2019) is not connecting via proxy server VM, winsrv2019 is not onboarded to Windows Defender Security Center web platform, I dont see winsrv2019 on the `Device Inventory` panel. On my winsrv2019, I made some registry changes, listed below:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d name:port
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyUser /t REG_SZ /d username
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyPass /t REG_SZ /d password
netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a service ticket with Microsoft Premier support, and they informed me that Windows Defender for Endpoint solution on Windows Server 2019 does not support authenticated proxy servers.